# How view recent changes to local repo in Git?

Tags: git, bash, git-stash

I'm working off of a big repo with lots of files. I've made minor changes in a lot of them (and haven't committed anything) and would like to be able to cycle through the history of changes to see exactly what was changed; similar to what happens if you use the `git stash -p` command. Is this possible?

Pretty much: I changed a lot of little things in different files and then something broke and I'm trying to figure which was the change that threw it all off.

Comment: Use `gitk`, it will open a window and let you browse.

Comment: If you haven't committed (or stashed or added to the index) any of your changes then git *cannot* help you figure this out because you haven't told git about any of the changes.

Comment: @DietrichEpp How is that supposed to help with changes that have only ever been in the working directory and have never been added/committed to git?

Comment: @EtanReisner plenty of commands look at the working tree, e.g. `git diff`.

Comment: @abligh Which isn't the question and isn't related to `gitk` in particular. The question is how to tell which *uncommitted edit* caused something to break.

Comment: My read is that he wants to be able to see the changes to see what has changed. I agree he can't get an ordering. But he can see all the individual changes (clearly they aren't in a *changeset*)

Comment: @EtanReisner: `gitk` shows uncommitted changes in addition to those which have been committed.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, but not differences *between* rounds of local changes which was the question. And in the sense that it shows that diff it is just `git diff` in a window (so again not really `gitk` itself that mattered). But the main point is that it missed the actual question being asked (at least as far as my reading of it goes).

Comment: @EtanReisner: The `git diff` command does not show you both the changes in the index and the changes in the tree in context, it just shoes one or the other (or both, combined).  The `gitk` command shows both.  I think it is "similar to `git stash -p`", as the asker requests.  I'm not exactly sure what you mean by *rounds* of local changes... could you be more specific?

Comment: @DietrichEpp `git stash -p` shows you the diff of the stash entry (against where it was stashed) in exactly the same way that `git diff` shows you the current working directory diff. It doesn't show "both" of anything. I am also not sure what you mean by "in context" here. I meant that it read to me like the OP made a change, then another, then another, etc. and that at some point in that series things broke and they would like to see the changes for each step. If that's not the case then yes, anything that will show you the overall diff is fine.

Comment: @EtanReisner: `gitk` will show you both `git diff` and `git diff --cached`.  That is about as good as it gets for changes in the working tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- you haven't committed anything
- you don't want to use a GUI

Options:

- `git status` tells you *what* you've changed (obviously)
- `git diff` (which tells you what *would* be staged if you did a `git add`
- `git diff [branchname/commit]` (which tells you the difference between the working tree and the branchname/commit - so `git diff HEAD` or `git diff master` are useful)
- Add `--patch` if you want a patch file
- Add `--stat` if you want stats.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Tortoise Git** software which will provide you with a GUI to view all the changes in every file.

Then go to your repository, right click(assuming you are using windows) and hover on TortoiseGit option and then choose *Check for modification* tab as show in picture below
[image: Working Directory]

This will open up a new dialog box for you to check which file was modified, with all details.

[image: Dialog box]
This dialog will show you every file that has changed in any way in your working tree, as well as any unversioned files you may have.

The dialog uses color coding to highlight the status.

#### Blue

Locally modified items.

#### Purple

Added items. Items which have been added with history have a + sign in the Text status column, and a tooltip shows where the item was copied from.

#### Dark red

Deleted or missing items.

#### Green

Items modified locally and in the repository. The changes will be merged on update. These may produce conflicts on update.

#### Bright red

Items modified locally and deleted in repository, or modified in repository and deleted locally. These will produce conflicts on update.

#### Black

Unchanged and un-versioned items.

From the context menu of the dialog you can show a diff of the changes. Check the local changes you made using **Context Menu → Compare with Base**. Check the changes in the repository made by others using **Context Menu → Show Differences** as Unified Diff.

You can also revert changes in individual files. If you have deleted a file accidentally, it will show up as Missing and you can use Revert to recover it.

Unversioned and ignored files can be sent to the recycle bin from here using **Context Menu → Delete**. If you want to delete files permanently (bypassing the recycle bin) hold the Shift key while clicking on Delete.

If you want to examine a file in detail, you can drag it from here into another application such as a text editor or IDE.

The columns are customizable. If you right click on any column header you will see a context menu allowing you to select which columns are displayed. You can also change column width by using the drag handle which appears when you move the mouse over a column boundary. These customizations are preserved, so you will see the same headings next time.

At the bottom of the dialog you can see a summary of the range of repository revisions in use in your working tree. These are the commit revisions, not the update revisions; they represent the range of revisions where these files were last committed, not the revisions to which they have been updated. Note that the revision range shown applies only to the items displayed, not to the entire working tree. If you want to see that information for the whole working tree you must check the Show unmodified files checkbox.